# Segmentation fault in recursive Binary Search Algorithm in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, binary-search

This is a C program with the recursive binary search algorithm, however when I run it, the debugger says there is an access segmentation fault in the binary search function.  Why is this and how do I fix this?

Here is the recursive binary search function:

```
int binSearch(int val, int numbers[], int low, int high)                 
{
     int mid;

     mid=(low+high)/2;
     if(val==numbers[mid])
     {  
                return(mid);          
     }   
     else if(val<numbers[mid])
     {
                return(binSearch(val, numbers, low, mid-1));               
     }            
     else if(val>numbers[mid])
     { 
                return(binSearch(val, numbers, mid+1, high));  
     }    
     else if(low==high)
     {
                return(-1);    
     }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you know where exactly it is seqfaulting? Can you try to move the last condition to the top of the function and see if it fixes it?

Comment: How do you call the function? *Where* is the crash (at which line)? Can you please show the debugger backtrace?

Comment: You do not ensure that low is actually lower than hight. Add a test for that.

Comment: the caller and the error message will be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must check `low == high` before `val < ...` and `val > ...` because otherwise `high` could become less than `low` and so your next recursion might calculate an invalid `mid`

Comment: what if `low` > `high` at the first place

Comment: @mathk I would call that an invalid call to `binSearch()` so it should be enough to require `low <= high` in the function's doc. But of course you could check it first if you preferred.

Comment: this is basic security check. Never trust the input.

Answer (score 2):

Your edge cases are off: specifically, when your `low` and `high` indices pass, you continue to call recursively before you reach the `low == high` test.  Rearrange the tests:

```
int binSearch(int val, int numbers[], int low, int high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (val == numbers[mid]) return mid;

    if (val < numbers[mid]) {
        if (mid > low) return binSearch(val, numbers, low, mid-1);
    } else if (val > numbers[mid]) {
        if (mid < high) return binSearch(val, numbers, mid+1, high);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Fixed if constructs in your code

```
int binSearch(int val, int numbers[], int low, int high)                 
{
     int mid;

     mid=(low+high)/2;

     if(low<=high)
     {
         if(val==numbers[mid])
           return mid;          

         else if(val<numbers[mid])
           return binSearch(val, numbers, low, mid-1);

        else 
          return binSearch(val, numbers, mid+1, high);  
     }
     else
           return -1;    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`low` < `high` is not ensure. If that is not the case your are going to search out of the array bound.

Add a sanity check for that.

```
if (low < high)
     return -1;
```

EDIT: as other point out you can also check if low == high at the beginning but that does not ensure that the first call of the function have sound value.